# ReferenceError, Function not Defined

Tags: php

I am very new to php and I tried to write this function. Now it seems like the function is not Defined. Nothing happens when I open the php file and if I try to use console to run it. It gives an error --

contentcheck('ex1.php','Bajestani')

ReferenceError: contentcheck is not defined

The Code is below.

```
<?php
if(contentcheck('ex1.php','Bajestani')===true)
    echo 'Got it';

function contentcheck($filename,$phrase)
{
    $content = shell_exec('C:\xampp\htdocs\docman\pdftotext '.$filename.' -');

    if (strpos($content,$phrase) !== false) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

if(contentcheck('ex1.php','Bajestani')===true)
    echo 'Got it';

?>
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: are you executing it as js or as php? because it seems you put it into a script tag

Comment: "ReferenceError: X is not defined" is a JavaScript error - not a PHP error. To build on @bwoebi's comment, are you attempting to call `contentcheck()` from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state that you try to run the function from the console.

In addition, `ReferenceError: contentcheck is not defined` is a Javascript error, not a PHP error.

Both of these facts lead me to the conclusion that you are trying to run the PHP code from inside the browser.

Please note that PHP code is not available from within the browser -- the function will indeed be undefined if you run it in the console, because PHP is run on the web server, not in the browser. The browser will never see your PHP functions; it simply sees the output of the PHP program (eg the HTML code, etc that is printed from by your PHP program). The PHP code itself is never seen by the browser.

It's not entirely clear what your program is supposed to be doing but what is clear is that the way you're trying to run it is not going to work. You're going to have to re-think this one completely, and possibly learn a bit more about how client/server systems work, and PHP in particular.

Comment: Thank you guys Its fixed. I realized that if I cannot use console to execute a  php function. And my code was ok and the reason I didnt get the expected result was that I passed ex1.php instead of ex1.pdf.